# Modifying taxonomy archive template on Wordpress with Neve Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Everyone,

I have installed Wordpress 5.3.2 with Neve Theme ver. 2.5.4. I anage custom post types and custom taxonomies with Pods 2.7.16.2.

I have a custom page type called "libros" (books, my website is for a publishing house). They have a custom taxonomy called "colección" (collection). I have the regular taxonomy archive page showing books like they were blog posts: Title, extract, read more... But what I need is it to show some custom fields from each book: book cover, title, author... However, I don't quite manage to understand how does this works. I have some basic php knowledge but it doesn't seems to be enough.

I have managed to figure out that this fragment of code is what do de magic of getting the pages info, but I don't know how to modify it to call custon fields info instead of treating them like blog posts.

```
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() ); 
                        if ( $pagination_type !== 'infinite' ) {
                            if ( $post_index === $hook_after_post && $hook_after_post !== - 1 ) {
                                do_action( 'neve_middle_posts_loop' );
                            }
                            $post_index ++;

                        }

                    }
```

I really appreciate all your help.